# Why the page is autoreload after get response from axios?

Tags: axios, fastapi

For example I want to press on button and get some result from my FASTAPi, the server gets the request but in my client side I dont get any response, so after debugging I figured out that 1 second after response the page is reloaded.
client:

```
document.getElementById('buttonid').addEventListener('click', generate);

function generate() {

    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/actions/upload2') .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Server:

```
from typing import List
from fastapi import APIRouter,Header,HTTPException,FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

router = APIRouter()



@router.get('/upload2')
def upload_file2():
    print('test')
    return {"hello": "world"}
```

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from routers import actions
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()


app.include_router(actions.router)
app.include_router(
    actions.router,
    prefix="/actions",
    tags=["actions"],
)

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['*'],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.get('/')
def hello_world():
    return {"Hello":"world"}
```

my server response:

```
test
INFO:     127.0.0.1:61223 - "GET /actions/upload2 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

and if I am using postman I get json: {"hello": "world"}

What is wrong?

Comment: INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: I tested your axios call and it works. Keep in mind that Uvicorn by default doesn't log the response, only the endpoint and the response status. Most likely the issues lies somewhere else in your client code. When you click the button do you see uvicorn logging the request?